# SKPhysicsBody avoid collision Swift/SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, physics

I have 3 SKSpriteNodes in my Scene. One **bird**, one **coin** and a **border** around the scene. I don't want the **coin** and the **bird** to collide with each other but withe the **border**.
I assign a different collisionBitMask and categoryBitMask to every node:

```
enum CollisionType:UInt32{
    case Bird  = 1
    case Coin = 2
    case Border = 3 
}
```

Like so:

```
bird.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionType.Bird.rawValue
bird.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CollisionType.Border.rawValue

coin.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionType.Coin.rawValue
coin.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CollisionType.Border.rawValue
```

But the **coin** and the **bird** still collide with each other.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bitmask is on 32 bits. Declaring them like you did corresponds to :

```
enum CollisionType:UInt32{
    case Bird = 1 // 00000000000000000000000000000001
    case Coin = 2 // 00000000000000000000000000000010
    case Border = 3 // 00000000000000000000000000000011
}
```

What you want to do is to set your border value to 4. In order to have the following bitmask instead :

```
enum CollisionType:UInt32{
    case Bird = 1 // 00000000000000000000000000000001
    case Coin = 2 // 00000000000000000000000000000010
    case Border = 4 // 00000000000000000000000000000100
}
```

*Keep in mind that you'll have to follow the same for next bitmask : 8, 16, ... an so on.*

**Edit :**

Also, you might want to use a struct instead of an enum and use another syntax to get it easier (it's not mandatory, just a matter of preference) :

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None       : UInt32 = 0
    static let All        : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let Bird       : UInt32 = 0b1       // 1
    static let Coin       : UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
    static let Border     : UInt32 = 0b100     // 4
}
```

That you could use like this :

```
bird.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bird
bird.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Border

coin.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Coin
coin.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Border
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a newbie in this topic. Can you maybe give me some link or keywords where I can find some more information about things like "UInt32 = 0b100"?

Comment: You're welcome. The syntax is "bit shifting", maybe the apple documentation ( http://goo.gl/DXVBJD ) is too complicated to start with. But, the basic idea is that the initial bit (1) representation is : 00000000000000000000000000000001. If you shift it from one bit, using either this syntax `0b10` or this one `0x1 << 1` the bit goes one place to the left : 00000000000000000000000000000010. You can shift it from two place using `0b100` or `0x1 << 2` and so on... :)

Comment: So, if I need for example another PhysicsCategory I could do  `static let Board     : UInt32 = 0b1000     // 8` right?

Comment: Sorry, I was responding other questions and trying to make a table for you. So those are bits, search for them on internet if needed. But to respond your question : yes you would do that. Here the table I made for you, it might help you understand better : http://goo.gl/Qmnr6a

Comment: WOW!! Men, you are awesome!!! Thank you so much for your work. Because of your table I now understand the principle of bit shifting.